# Hairpin structure easy algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a structure with letters A, Z, F, G.

A have a pair with Z, and F with G.

I have for example AAAFFZZGGFFGGAAAAZZZZ. And I need to "curve" structure and that fold will make a pairs

```
A A A F F Z Z G G F F -
  * *     * *     * *  |
  Z Z Z Z A A A A G G -
```

6 pairs in upper example.

But we can create structure like this:

```
      A A A F F Z Z G G -
      *             * *  |
Z Z Z Z A A A A G G F F -
```

And head is a fragment of structure where pairs cannot exists. For example head 2:

rozmiar. Na przykład head = 2:

```
                    F F
A A A F F Z Z G G  /   \
  * *     * *           |
  Z Z Z Z A A A A  \   /
                    G G
```

I don't know how to find maximal number of pairs that can be created in this structure

Comment: Is AAAFFZZGGFFGGAAAAZZZZ a string? Or a different data structure?

Comment: Can you count the pairs if I tell you where the wrap happens? If so, can you brute force an answer from there?

Comment: You seem to want to predict secondary structure of a polymer - can you give some more background info?  You could use algorithms for predicting RNA secondary structure, but I'm not sure if there is software to solve your problem out of the box, or if you would need to implement your own.

Comment: with RNA, there is a different stability depending on the nucleotide pairs, is this the same here? or are A/Z and F/G pairs equivalent?

Comment: Your examples show alignments without any gaps. Are gaps allowed?

Comment: It's a string or list of letters

Comment: And gaps are not allower, technically I need to move curve of each letter and count pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the matching go faster you can prepare a second string (R) with the letters flipped to their corresponding values.  This will allow direct comparisons of paired positions instead of going through an indirection n^2 times:

```
S = "AAAFFZZGGFFGGAAAAZZZZ"

match = str.maketrans("AZFG","ZAGF")
R = S.translate(match)                # flipped matching letters

mid = len(S)//2
maxCount,maxPos = 0,0
for d in range(mid+1):        # moving away from middle
    for p in {mid+d,mid-d}:   # right them left  
        pairs = sum(a==b for a,b in zip(S[p-1::-1],R[p:])) # match fold
        if pairs>maxCount:
            maxCount,maxPos = pairs,p  # track best so far and fold position
    if p <= maxCount: break            # stop when impossible to improve 
        
print(maxCount)                         # 6 matches
print(maxPos)                           # folding at 11
print(S[:maxPos].rjust(len(S)))         #          AAAFFZZGGFF
print(S[maxPos:][::-1].rjust(len(S)))   #           ZZZZAAAAGG
                                        #           **  **  **
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start with testing the folding point in the center, and then fan out (in zig-zag manner) putting the folding point further from the center.

Then for a given folding point, count the allowed pairs. You can use slicing to create the two strips, one in reversed order, and then `zip` those to get the pairs.

The outer iteration (determining the folding point) can stop when the size of the shortest strip is shorter than the size of the best answer found so far.

Here is a solution, which also returns the actual fold, so it can be printed for verification:

```
def best_fold(chain):
    allowed = set(("AZ","ZA","FG","GF"))
    revchain = chain[::-1]
    maxnumpairs = 0
    fold = chain  # This represents "no solution"
    n = len(chain)
    head = n // 2
    for diff in range(n):
        head += diff if diff % 2 else -diff
        if head - 2 < maxnumpairs or n - head - 2 < maxnumpairs:
            break
        numpairs = sum(a+b in allowed
            for a, b in zip(revchain[-head+2:], chain[head+2:])
        )
        if numpairs > maxnumpairs:
            maxnumpairs = numpairs
            fold = chain[:head].rjust(n) + "\n" + revchain[:-head].rjust(n)        

    return maxnumpairs, fold
```

Here is how to run it on the example string:

```
numpairs, fold = best_fold("AAAFFZZGGFFGGAAAAZZZZ")
print(numpairs)  # 5
print(fold)      #   AAAFFZZGGF
                 #  ZZZZAAAAGGF
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first start with a suitable data type to implement your creasable string. Now first things first, as you mention in your comment we can use list of characters which is better than a string. Then perhaps a tuple of arrays like `[[Char],[Char]]` would be sufficient.

Also creasing from left or right shouldn't matter so for simplicity we start with;

```
[ ["A","A","F","F","Z","Z","G","G","F","F","G","G","A","A","A","A","Z","Z","Z","Z"]
, ["A"]
]
```

then in every step;

1. Then in every step we can map our list of characters into a a tuple of creases like

   `chars.map((_,i,a) => [a.slice(i+1),a.slice(0,i+1).reverse()]`
2. Compare and count for pairs.

In order to make an efficient comparison of corresponding items being a valid pair, a simple look up table as below can be used

```
{ "A": "Z"
, "Z": "A"
, "G": "F"
, "F": "G"
}
```

3. Finally we can filter the longest one(s)

An implementation of creases could be like;

```js
function pairs(cs){
  var lut = { "A": "Z"
            , "Z": "A"
            , "G": "F"
            , "F": "G"
            };
  return cs.map(function(_,i,a){
                  var crs = [a.slice(i+1),a.slice(0,i+1).reverse()]; // console.log(crs) to see all creases)
                  return crs[0].reduce( (ps,c,j) => lut[c] === crs[1][j] ? ( ps.res.push([c,crs[1][j],j])
                                                                           , ps.crs ??= crs.concat(i+1)
                                                                           , ps
                                                                           )
                                                                         : ps
                                      , { res: []
                                        , crs: null
                                        }
                                      );
                })
           .reduce( (r,d) => r.length ? r[r.length-1].res.length > d.res.length ? r   : 
                                        r[r.length-1].res.length < d.res.length ? [d] : r.concat(d)
                                      : [d]
                  , []
                  );
}

var chars   = ["A","A","A","F","F","Z","Z","G","G","F","F","G","G","A","A","A","A","Z","Z","Z","Z"],
    result  =  pairs(chars);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
 max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Now this is a straightforward algorithm and possibly not the most efficient one. It can be made more faster by using complex modular arithmetic on testing pairs without using any additional arrays however i believe it would be an overkill and very hard to explain.